# Is TimeZone.getDSTSavings() in java returns always positive value?

Tags: java, android

Is TimeZone.getDSTSavings() in java returns always positive value or Negative values also?

I have tried this way

```
        long millisecondsForGivenDateTime = 0l;
        if (TimeZone.getTimeZone(strTZID).inDaylightTime(
                new Date(millisecondsForGivenDateTime))) {
            millisecondsForGivenDateTime = (millisecondsForGivenDateTime + TimeZone
                    .getTimeZone(strTZID).getDSTSavings());
        }
```

here strTZID is timezone id dynamically passed to this function and millisecondsForGivenDateTime contains the dynamic value.

I am always getting 3600000 or 0 won't this function return -3600000?

Answer (score 1):

In theory it *could* return a negative value - if you were using a `TimeZone` subclass where daylight saving time caused clocks to go back rather than forward.

I very much doubt you'll see that in the wild, although I *have* seen something similar in the Windows time zone database to get around the fact that Windows couldn't cope with time zones changing their standard UTC offset... if a zone went from UTC+5 to UTC+6 (as standard time) for example - and stopped observing DST - the zone data indicated that "DST" was actually -1 hour, and just inverted when it was in effect from what humans would expect. I've seen this with the Russian time zone, although I believe the data is cleaner now.

The desktop JRE prevents you from constructing a `SimpleTimeZone` with negative DST savings, but I don't know whether the same (undocumented) limitation is present in Android. You could always create your own subclass of `TimeZone` which *did* return a negative offset though.

Answer (score 0):

This class returns 3600000 (1 hour) for time zones that use daylight savings time and 0 for timezones that do not, leaving it to subclasses to override this method for other daylight savings offsets.

If it were returning both positive and negative values, that would cause a two hour difference between the seasons.

Comment: "that would cause a two hour difference between the seasons" - not sure where you get that from.

Comment: Then how can I determine the DST time for the countries which set back their clock by 1 hour?.

Comment: Typically, users of DST adjust clocks forward one hour near the start of spring and adjust them backward in the autumn to "normal" or regular time. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time)

Comment: Yes, *typically* it's an hour ahead - but I would assume that a time zone returning a negative offset was doing so deliberately... so there wouldn't be a "two hour difference".

Comment: @JohnBritto: Can you give an example of a country which sets its clock *back* by one hour for DST, instead of forward? Some countries will move their clocks back in the first half of the year and forward in the second half of the year, but it's the "forward" part that is DST in that case. While negative DST is *feasible*, I don't know of any countries that actually work that way.